# Существует ли список кодировок?

Tags: кодировка, unicode, cp1251

Пример: "UTF-8", "ASCII", "Windows-1252", "ISO-8859-15", "ISO-8859-1", "ISO-8859-6", "CP1256"

Полный список бы возможных кодировок найти... Где можно посмотреть?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Набор_символов

Comment: https://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml

Comment: Одних двоично-десятичных кодов больше миллиона. Полный - это вряд ли...

Comment: @PinkTux там не все DOS32 например нет

Comment: Теоретически никакого полного списка быть не может, потому что я вот прям щас могу выдумать совершенно новую кодировку, которой нигде не будет :D

Comment: А что такое "кодировка DOS32"? Не припомню такой вообще.

Comment: Достаточно представительный список кодировок можно увидеть запустив команду `iconv -l` (Linux)

Comment: @avp точно спасибо!, вынесите в ответ

Comment: Интересно помнит ли кто-то КОИ-7)

Comment: @АлександрМартынцев ага, и перфоленты

Comment: @avp только вот `Следующий список содержит все известные встроенные кодировки. Это не
обязательно означает, что можно использовать любые комбинации данных
имён в параметрах командной строки FROM и TO. Одна и та же кодировка
может быть указана под несколькими именами (псевдонимами).`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, что "вот"? Где-то в вопросе были какие-то дополнительные ограничения?

Comment: @PinkTux не лишним будет это упомянуть

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, дельное замечание (кроме того, я не уверен, что это **все известные** кодировки)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно представительный список кодировок можно увидеть запустив команду `iconv -l`
 (в Linux)

Answer (score 1):

В свое время собрал такой список:

```
65001   (UTF-8)
65000   (UTF-7)
37  (IBM EBCDIC - США и Канада)
437 (OEM-США)
500 (IBM EBCDIC - международная)
708 (арабская - ASМО)
720 (арабская - прозрачная ASМО)
737 (OEM - греческая 437G)
775 (OEM - балтийская)
850 (OEM - многоязычная латиница 1)
852 (OEM - латиница 2)
855 (OEM - кириллица традиционная)
857 (OEM-турецкая)
858 (OEM - многоязычная латиница 1 + Евро)
860 (OEM-португальская)
861 (OEM-исландская)
862 (OEM-иврит)
863 (OEM - Франко-канадская)
864 (OEM-арабская)
865 (OEM-скандинавская)
866 (OEM-русская)
869 (OEM - греческая современная)
870 (IBM EBCDIC - многоязычная/ROECE (латиница-2))
874 (ANSI/OEM - тайская)
875 (IBM EBCDIC - современная греческая)
932 (AN SI/OЕМ - японская Shift-JIS)
936 (ANSI/OEM - китайская упрощенная GBK)
949 (ANSI/OEM - корейская)
950 (ANSI/OEM - китайская традиционная Big5)
1026    (IBM EBCDIC - турецкая (латиница-5))
1047    (IBM EBCDIC - латиница-1/Open System)
1140    (IBM EBCDIC - США/Канада (37 + евро))
1141    (IBM EBCDIC - немецкая (20273 + евро))
1142    (IBM EBCDIC - датская/норвежская (20277 + евро))
1143    (IBM EBCDIC - финская/шведская (20278 + евро))
1144    (IBM EBCDIC - итальянская (20280 + евро))
1145    (IBM EBCDIC - латиноам/испанская (20284 + евро))
1146    (IBM EBCDIC - британская (20285 + евро))
1147    
1148    (IBM EBCDIC - международная (500 + евро))
1149    (IBM EBCDIC - исландская (20871 +евро))
1250    (ANSI - центрально-европейская)
1251    (ANSI - кириллица)
1252    (ANSI - латиница 1)
1253    (ANSI - греческая)
1254    (ANSI-турецкая)
1255    (ANSI-иврит)
1256    (ANSI-арабская)
1257    (ANSI-балтийская)
1258    (ANSI/OEM-вьетнамская)
1361    (корейская-Johab)
10000   (MAC - Латиница
10001   (MAC - Японская
10002   (MAC - Китайская традиционная  Big5
10003   (MAC - Корейская
10004   (MAC - Арабская
10005   (MAC - Иврит
10006   (MAC - Греческая 1
10007   (MAC - Кириллица
10008   (MAC - Китайская упрощенная GB 2312
10010   (MAC - Румынская
10017   (MAC - Украинская
10021   (MAC - Тайская
10029   (MAC - Латиница 2
10079   (MAC - Исландская
10081   (MAC - Турецкая
10082   (MAC - Хорватская
20000   (CNS - тайваньская)
20001   (ТСА - тайваньская)
20002   (Eten - тайваньская)
20003   (IBM5550 - тайваньская)
20004   (TeleText - тайваньская)
20005   (Wang - тайваньская)
20105   (IA5 IRV международный алфавит N-5)
20106   (IA5 немецкая)
20107   (IA5 шведская)
20108   (IA5 норвежская)
20127   (США-ASCII)
20261   (Т.61)
20269   (ISO 6937 - диакритические знаки)
20273   (IBM EBCDIC - немецкая)
20277   (IBM EBCDIC - датская/норвежская)
20278   (IBM EBCDIC - Финская/шведская)
20280   (IBM EBCDIC - итальянская)
20284   (IBM EBCDIC - латиноамериканская/испанская)
20285   (IBM EBCDIC - британская)
20290   (IBM EBCDIC - японская расширенная катакана) 
20297   (IBM EBCDIC - Французская)
20420   (IBM EBCDIC-арабская)
20423   (IBM EBCDIC - греческая)
20424   (IBM EBCDIC-иврит)
20833   (IBM EBCDIC - корейская расширенная)
20838   (IBM EBCDIC - тайская)
20866   (русская - КОИ8)
20871   (IBM EBCDIC - исландская)
20880   (IBM EBCDIC - кириллица (русская))
20905   (IBM EBCDIC - турецкая)
20924   (IBM EBCDIC - латиница 1/Open System (1047 + евро))
20932   (JIS X 0208-1990 и 0212-1990)
20936   (Китайский упрощенный GB2312)
20949   
21025   (IBM EBCDIC - кириллица (сербская, болгарская)) 
21027   (расш. Алф. нижний регистр)
21866   (украинская - КОИ8-U)
28591   (ISO 8859-1 латиница 1)
28592   (ISO 8859-2 центральноевропейская)
28593   (ISO 8859-3 латиница 3)
28594   (ISO 8859-4 балтийская)
28595   (ISO 8859-5 кириллица)
28596   (ISO 8859-6 арабская)
28597   (ISO 8859-7 греческая)
28598   (ISO 8859-8 иврит: визуальная сортировка)
28599   (ISO 8859-9 латиница 5)
28603   (ISO 8859-13 латиница 7)
28605   (ISO 8859-15 латиница 9)
38598   (ISO 8859-8 иврит: логическая сортировка)
50220   (ISO-2022 японская без полуширинной катаканы)
50221   
50222   (ISO-2022 японская JIS X 0201-1989)
50225   (ISO-2022 корейская)
50227   (ISO-2022 китайская упрощенная)
50229   (ISO-2022 китайская традиционная)
51949   (EUC корейская)
52936   (HZ-GB2312 китайская упрощенная)
54936   (G В18030 Китайский упрощенный)
57002   (ISCII деванагари)
57003   (ISCII бенгальская)
57004   (ISCII тамильская)
57005   (ISCII телугу)
57006   (ISCII ассамская)
57007   (ISCII ория)
57008   (ISCII каннада)
57009   (ISCII малаялам)
57010   (ISCII гуджарати)
57011   (ISCII - панджаби (гурмухи))
```